# Smooth anmiation with LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, movement, vector

I want to move a enemy from its current position toward the mouse position in LibGDX.
**x, y** - enemy position   **saveX, saveY** - position where my enemy need to go(or mouse position saved at specific time) **xSize, ySize** - enemy size.

```
protected Vector2 makeVec(float saveX, float saveY){
    Vector2 v = new Vector2(saveX - x, saveY - y);
    return v.nor();
}

public void update(float dt){
    test += dt;
    dtTime += dt;
    if(cont){
        vec = makeVec(saveX, saveY);
        x += vec.x * speed
        y += vec.y * speed;
        cont = cont();
    }
}
```

But for some reasons my enemy movement animation is not smooth. What's wrong?

Comment: Don't create a new Vector2 in each update call. Creating new objects in the update method can lead to stutter (in this case probably not, but it's still better to reuse the vector).

Answer (score 1):

The distance moved does not take the delta time into account, so if you get updates coming at an irregular interval you'll get jerky motion.

Scale your `speed` by the elapsed time, `dt`;

```
public void update(float dt){
    if(cont == true){
        vec = makeVec();
        x += vec.x * speed * dt;
        y += vec.y * speed * dt;
    }
}
```

This might mean you'll want to increase the speed.

Comment: In addition to this, you want to cap the delta so that if it's greater than some value (like 100ms), you want to run it in increments of up to 100ms.

Comment: Ok, but my movement now is very very slow.

Comment: So then you increase the value of your speed variable until you get the speed you want.